# Same colour for same category in different graphs in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, colors, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to know how to fix the colours for a graph in Excel 2016, such that category 1 is always red, category 2 always blue, etc., because I want to draw several graphs, one for each firm I look at.

One problem is that, though there are many common categories, not all categories show up in each graph, so making a template probably doesn't work.

The graph could be a bar plot, line plot, stacked columns, percentages, etc., depending on the data.

Do you know how to...

1) fix the colours WITHOUT USING VBA? (I only found answers for VBA.)

2) if I have to use VBA, what would be my very first step, since I am a total newbie?

Comment: You can create a chart template. See [this answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1236523/excel-color-templates-for-charts/1236547#1236547).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Color templates for charts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1236523/excel-color-templates-for-charts)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately not all categories show up in all graphs, i.e. the order won't always be the same :-(

Comment: Hard to do without VBA, since it would require data- and layout-specific formulas. For a VBA approach, check out my tutorial [VBA Conditional Formatting of Charts by Category Label](https://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-category-label/).

Comment: The fact that ‘‘not all categories show up in each graph’’ is (as you probably realize) the heart of your problem.   Have you investigated ways to include all categories in all graphs (so they get the right color), but then suppress the display of the ones you don’t want in a particular chart?

Comment: That's a good idea! But for me sometimes suppressing outputs also changed the colors?! If you're sure it doesn't, then you can suggest it as an answer and I'll test and accept it.